A novel about foam creatures that devoured the Earth
Read this book back in the mid 2010's about scientists who accidentally unleashed this foam creature from experimenting with bone marrow. I remember that they kept calling it Earth's white blood cells, and the creatures only attacked humans as a way to cleanse the Earth. The creatures spread through this cloud/mist. Humanity discovers towards the end that the foam is dissolved with water, so they try to fight back using water cannons, but they get overwhelmed regardless. I also remember that at the end, before one of the characters get eaten, he walks into the mist singing the Battle Hymn of the Republic.

Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Do you happen to recall the cover art?  Was this a physical book or an e-book?

Is this The Tomorrow Code (2008) by Brian Falkner...?
From a review:

Tane and Rebecca, 14-year-olds living in Auckland, receive coded messages from their future selves, warning about an apocalyptic event that only they can prevent. As they decipher the clues and race to take the right steps to save lives, readers are swept into visions of ecological disaster and a planet fighting back.

As noted above, the plot involves a pair of teenagers who receive coded messages from the future warning them of an apocalyptic event. This event takes the form of a mysterious white fog that begins spreading across Auckland; within it are creatures resembling jellyfish and snowmen that dissolve everyone they touch.
The protagonists eventually realise that the creatures are antibodies and macrophages produced by the Earth's immune system and keyed to dissolve human cells as if we were pathogens. This phenomenon was triggered by the Chimera Project, an experiment involving bone marrow and the gene-splicing of antibodies in an attempt to produce a generic antibody effective against any kind of rhinovirus.
It's determined that while bullets have little effect on the creatures, high-pressure jets of saltwater can blast them apart and prevent them from reforming. A group of American soldiers march into battle against the creatures armed with water blasters and singing "The Battle Hymn of the Republic," but are ultimately overwhelmed by sheer numbers and killed.


The Tomorrow Code is the correct answer to this question.
Source: I wrote it.
If you have any other questions regarding the book, please ask.

While we always appreciate an author showing up, we also do ask that all answers provide full details.

What kind of full details are you looking for?

https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9444/23243
